# Is there a way to import emails in Microsoft format MSG into newly installed Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, import

I have 3500 emails from old Outlook in one folder. All the emails are in file format: MSG . They were somehow downloaded / exported from the old laptop when the user was using Outlook and knew that he has to backup those emails.

Now, I need to import these emails into newly installed Outlook 2007 on Windows 7.
Once I import them, I will look for all emails that were sent from 1 particular sender who has 1 particular email address and also for all emails that were sent to this particular user (let's say the user we are talking about has an email address: john.smith@gmail.com).

So what I need is to filter only emails which were sent to and received from one email address.   It would took me a long time to open each and every of those 3500 emails, that's why I'm looking for some quicker solution.

Maybe it would be easier to do it in other application than Outlook but I thought that importing old emails to Outlook is easy. It seems it's not.

Comment: What version of outlook was used to export those files? Why can't you just `Drag` and `Drop` the files into Outlook.

Comment: @Ramhound, this really should be answer mate, not a comment (IMO). :)

Comment: @DaveRook - If I post an answer to just use Drag and Drop it will be downvoted.

Comment: Drag and drop worked! Thank you @Ramhound, it took me more than 5 hours to find the solution ... You saved me... ;-)

Comment: @EinsteinsGrandson - I found it by doing a google search on the search phrase ".MSG import Office 2007" I found multiple articles and support threads on the subject.

Comment: @Ramhound, I understand, but that is reflection on the audience/users then, not your excellent answer! We'll mark it as answer in essence :)

Comment: @DaveRook - Problem solved posted it as a community wiki.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? It was you Dave? I was solving this problem  for free for somebody else not for myself, investing my precious time!

Comment: No, I didn't. I do downvote, but always leave a reason why. Either way, I would imagine some one downvoted you for making no research effort at all.

Comment: I have been doing the research for 5 hours... Somehow, I was unlucky...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `Drag` and `Drop` the files from Explorer into Outlook